# Shopware 6 exceptions which can be safely ignored

Tags: sentry, shopware6

We are using Sentry (via the [monitoring plugin](https://store.shopware.com/jopso14222178127/monitoring-suite-fuer-shopware-6.html), which we are not affilated with), which can send you an email on each exception, to monitor our Shopware 6 shops and saw that there are some exceptions where useless to report.

We want to collect exception classes which are safe to ignore, because they are more an user error than a system error or caused by spam bots, such as the entry of a wrong password or wrong CSRF tokens.

It's up to everyone on their own if they ignore those exceptions in Sentry themselves (giving the possibility to still get alerts if an exception affects more users than normal) or suppress the sending of those exceptions to Sentry completely.

In the long run it might make sense to consider converting those exceptions to normal log messages in the Shopware core code.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of Exceptions which you can ignore. We are right now working  on improving our exceptions to improve logging to reduce them a lot.

https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/d30fb70ad557154621b03bcb13ac1563d87005a4

Comment: Interesting commit - while those exceptions I mentioned are not listed there... Wondering if there is difference in 6.5 (because our findings are still based on 6.4)

Answer (score 2):

Format:

`Exception class - message`

Explanation why it should be safe to ignore

---

`League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException - The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.`

`League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException - The refresh token is invalid.`

`League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException - credentials were incorrect.`

Wrong credentials or tokens in the admin panel

`Shopware\Storefront\Framework\Captcha\Exception\CaptchaInvalidException - The provided value for captcha "Shopware\Storefront\Framework\Captcha\HoneypotCaptcha" is not valid.`

`Shopware\Storefront\Framework\Csrf\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException - The provided CSRF token is not valid`

caused by (SPAM) bots

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of the mentioned Monitoring Extension. Thank you for pointing me to this thread.

I've created an internal Issue to find a way to provide an option to exclude Exceptions that can be ignored safely, based on the above answers.

Comment: v2.1.0 of the Plugin can now filters those exceptions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76389141/288568